# jQuery: detect when input value is changed indirectly (up/down buttons)

Tags: jquery

I have an input and two buttons up/down to increase/decrease the value of the input.

I can detect when the input value is changed directly (writing inside the input), but.. how to detect when the input value is changed with the up/down buttons.

NOTE: I should send ajax request evertytime the value of input is changed.

```
<input type="text" value="0">
<button class="up">UP</button>
<button class="down">DOWN</button>      

$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("input").on("keyup change input", function(){
        alert("foo");
    });
    });

    $(".up").on("click", function(){
        alert("bar");
        $('input').val(parseInt($('input').val()) + parseInt(1));
    });
```

Comment: You can use the click event on the buttons, as you already do (to alert "bar")?

Comment: Why can't you call a common function that sends ajax request on click of the buttons as well..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually trigger the change event when pressing the buttons:

```
$(".up").on("click", function(){
    alert("bar");
    $('input').val(parseInt($('input').val()) + parseInt(1)).trigger('change');
});
```